# Multiple requests with Include and Where condtition throws exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core-1.0

I am using ASP.NET core with EF core.
If i do multiple requests to the same Controller method some of thoes requests throws: `Object reference not set to an instance of an object`, without detailed explanation. However if i do one request to this controller- no exception occur.

Here i reconstructed example of my existing system

```
    public class Player
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Team Team { get; set; }
}

public class Team
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Player> Players { get; set; }

}
```

This code throws exception

```
    public async Task<List<Player>> TEST()
    {
        using (Repository.DataProvider.RepoDbContext db = new Repository.DataProvider.RepoDbContext())
        {
           return await  db.Players.Include(x => x.Team).Where(x => x.Team.Id == 1).ToListAsync();
        }
    }
```

[image]

I did a little research and realize that this exceptions occurs only if there is combination with `Include` and `where` statement using the same property (`Team` in this case). If i remove `include` or `where` everything works fine.

Is this some sort of bug or i am doing something wrong?

Data from player table:
[image]

***EDIT:***
reproduce problem
https://github.com/brivvirs/EFCoreBug

Comment: I have for 4 players with specified team. In 'real world' example Team has Required Attribute

Comment: In that case it's a non-repro. Please read [ask] and provide a [mcve]. Show the actual request you issue to the API and the actual code that runs. You definitely didn't run into an EF bug, using `Include()` and `Where()` on the same navigation property runs millions of times a day.

Comment: How does my questions refers to  'What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it? '?

Comment: Because that's the exception you claim to get. The code you show does not throw that exception. Please see my previous comment and [edit] your question so that it actually reflects your actual problem and code.

Comment: Good to know...

Comment: Migration EF core from 1.0.0 to 1.1.0 version fixed this bug.